# Html form redirect to a url

Tags: php, forms

I'm not very good with php but looking to add a contact form to my html. I found this on line and it seems to work, however I wish to redirect when the form is submitted to another html page.

Please can you help

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['email'])) {

    // CHANGE THE TWO LINES BELOW
    $email_to = "test@testing.com";

    $email_subject = "Testing";


    function died($error) {
        // your error code can go here
        echo "We are very sorry, but there were error(s) found with the form you submitted. ";
        echo "These errors appear below.<br /><br />";
        echo $error."<br /><br />";
        echo "Please go back and fix these errors.<br /><br />";
        die();
    }

    // validation expected data exists
    if(!isset($_POST['first_name']) ||
        !isset($_POST['last_name']) ||
        !isset($_POST['email']) ||
        !isset($_POST['telephone']) ||
        !isset($_POST['comments'])) {
        died('We are sorry, but there appears to be a problem with the form you submitted.');      
    }

    $first_name = $_POST['first_name']; // required
    $last_name = $_POST['last_name']; // required
    $email_from = $_POST['email']; // required
    $telephone = $_POST['telephone']; // not required
    $comments = $_POST['comments']; //  required

    $error_message = "";
    $email_exp = '/^[A-Za-z0-9._%-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\.[A-Za-z]{2,4}$/';
  if(!preg_match($email_exp,$email_from)) {
    $error_message .= 'The Email Address you entered does not appear to be valid.<br />';
  }
    $string_exp = "/^[A-Za-z .'-]+$/";
  if(!preg_match($string_exp,$first_name)) {
    $error_message .= 'The First Name you entered does not appear to be valid.<br />';
  }
  if(!preg_match($string_exp,$last_name)) {
    $error_message .= 'The Last Name you entered does not appear to be valid.<br />';
  }
  if(strlen($comments) < 2) {
    $error_message .= 'The Comments you entered do not appear to be valid.<br />';
  }
  if(strlen($error_message) > 0) {
    died($error_message);
  }
    $email_message = "Form details below.\n\n";

    function clean_string($string) {
      $bad = array("content-type","bcc:","to:","cc:","href");
      return str_replace($bad,"",$string);
    }

    $email_message .= "First Name: ".clean_string($first_name)."\n";
    $email_message .= "Last Name: ".clean_string($last_name)."\n";
    $email_message .= "Email: ".clean_string($email_from)."\n";
    $email_message .= "Telephone: ".clean_string($telephone)."\n";
    $email_message .= "Comments: ".clean_string($comments)."\n";


// create email headers
$headers = 'From: '.$email_from."\r\n".
'Reply-To: '.$email_from."\r\n" .
'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();
@mail($email_to, $email_subject, $email_message, $headers); 
?>

<!-- place your own success html below -->

Thank you for contacting us. We will be in touch with you very soon.

<?php
}
die();
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove the last `die();` and add

```
header('Location: http://www.yoursite.com/yourpage');
```

Remove also:

```
<!-- place your own success html below -->
Thank you for contacting us. We will be in touch with you very soon.
```

Answer (score 0):

> First remove last **die();** from your code
>
> for redirection
>
> When Your HTML Code comes before / Above **header("Location:xyz.com/")** 
>   then **header('Location:xyz.com/")** redirection not work. So write
>   header(Location) before html code.
>
> If you want to redirect to another page after html code then use
>   **location.href** javascript method.

Answer (score 0):

Add `ob_start();` at the top of the file. This sets output buffering so that you can set headers later on if any output is echoed.

To redirect, add

```
header('location: location-to-file.php');
```

This will redirect after the script has finished executing.

Comment: I am getting this when I run the changes:Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /home/content/16/10154316/html/testing/html_form_send.php:11) in /home/content/16/10154316/html/testing/html_form_send.php on line 90